# Android image movement

Tags: android, eclipse

I have images moving animation in my layout, what I want to happen is that when I click the image, the animation will retart, it will return to the starting point. this is my new code, please help

public class Game extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    final ImageView chips = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chips);

      final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation.setDuration(9000);
      animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
      animation.setFillAfter(true);
      chips.startAnimation(animation);

      chips.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (animation != null) {
                animation.reset();
               chips.setAnimation(null);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the animation status and remove it from the ImageView:
Touch screen:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        animation.reset();
        bula1.setAnimation(null);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

or touch image view:

```
bula1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (animation != null) {
                    animation.reset();
                    bula1.setAnimation(null);
                }

                return true;
            }

        });
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: The method is overrided in your Activity. So if you touch the screen, it will pause the animation. If you only want to touch the image view, you need to set a touch event listener for it

Comment: it works, but when i click the image, it will be sstuck in its starting point, wwhat i want to happen iss whn i click, it will go to the starting point and fall again.

Comment: another thing, when the image is halfway the screen, i cant click it anymore.